# File Download with wget

Tags: web, automation, wget

On the following web page:
http://www.noel.gv.at/wasserstand/static/stations/109710/station.html
there is a link for the monthly statistics concerning rainfall at different locations in Lower Austria.
I have already used wget to download files but to be honest I am not able to find out which url to use (or is used) if I click 'Monat' (German for month, next to the excel symbol).
How can I automate the mouse click with wget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot automate mouse clicks with wget, you will need some sort of automated browser for that (Selenium).

I did succeed in locating the download URL by clicking on "Monat", then pressing **CTRL+J** in Chrome (opens the download history, you can also go to **chrome://downloads/** in the address bar). You will see the download URL there.
You can use that URL with **wget** successfully.

Comment: Thanks a lot now I now how to proceed